# At what point does comparing between an "integer" and a "float" equals `true`?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

I understand about [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and [`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER).

I understand that `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2` equals true.

But I've only recently realised that:

```js
var number = 2007199254740991;
var float  = 2007199254740991.123;

console.log(number === float);
// => true
```

But

```js
var number = 1007199254740991;
var float  = 1007199254740991.123;

console.log(number === float);
// => false
```

So my question is, how do we find the "max safe float"?

**EDIT**

My question:

At what point does comparing between an "integer" and a "float" equals `true`?

Comment: There are no floats and integers in JS - every number is represented by IEEE 754 float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking when comparing fails is the wrong question. Comparing two numbers always works correctly; it evaluates to true if and only if the two numbers being compared have the same value.

The problem actually occurs in earlier operations. Converting a numeral in source code to a `Number`, adding numbers, and other operations introduce errors when the exact real-number mathematical value is rounded to a value representable in floating-point.

JavaScript uses IEEE-754 binary64, which has a 53-bit significand (the fraction portion of a floating-point number). This means any number with a magnitude of 2<sup>52</sup> or greater does not have any bits that can represent values less than 1—they have no fraction portion. So, when any number 2<sup>52</sup> or greater is converted to a JavaScript `Number`, the result is an integer.

But smaller numbers are rounded too. From 2<sup>51</sup> to 2<sup>52</sup>, the least significant bit available represents 2<sup>−1</sup>, or ½. So any number in this interval that is converted to a `Number` must produce either an integer or an integer plus ½. That means some numbers, like 225179981368524**8.6**, will produce non-integers (225179981368524**8.5**), while others, like 225179981368524**8.8** will produce integers (225179981368524**9**).

At every magnitude below 2<sup>52</sup>, there are some numbers that will be rounded to integers when converted to `Number` and some numbers that will not be rounded to integers. (Above 2<sup>52</sup>, all numbers are rounded to integers.) At smaller magnitudes, only numbers closer to integers are rounded to integers—the format becomes more “sensitive” as the magnitude decreases.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing, because Javascript numbers have limited precision, or significant digits (effectively).

```js
const n1 = 1e-10;
const n2 = 1e-30;
console.log(n1 - n2 === n1);
```

Even a very small number like `1e-10` will have imprecise behavior when manipulated in combination with numbers significantly smaller than it. The same sort of thing is happening with your snippet - ~`1e15` (close to the value of your `1007199254740991`) is too large in comparison to `0.123`.

There's also the famous imprecise 0.1 + 0.2:

```js
console.log(0.1 + 0.2);
```

In addition to significant digits being effectively limited, numbers which cannot be *precisely* represented in binary will have this sort of problem.

Comment: Can we find at what point does the representations become "imprecise"?

Comment: Well, there is [`Number.EPSION`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) for the minimum representable value between 1 and the next distinct number. [Further reading on floating point arithmetic (also has lots of links)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @YongQuan I *think* any number which isn't accurately representable using binary can't be trusted. Eg, mathematical manipulations of `0.5`, `0.25`, `0.125`, `0.625` around the same order of magnitude work, because they can be represented perfectly in binary, but any other decimal number isn't.

Comment: @CertainPerformance just to clarify - `0.5` is `2 ^ -1`, and since it's a power of two, it can be easily represented in bits. Same idea with `0.25` (`2 ^ -2`) and `0.125` (`2 ^ -3`). That's why those values are "better" than, say, `0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can't find a "max safe float" in JavaScript. It simply doesn't exist.

@CertainPerformance is right, there's a limited precision in JS. Besides, remember that a number in a programming language is stored by 0 or 1 bits, and remember that you can have infinite decimals, so... can you have infinite 0's and 1's? .

As any computer can store infinite numbers, there's no max safe float number.